# Twitter bootstrap and iPad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've trying to learn to use Twitter bootstrap.  It works well with the desktop and the responsive works.  Let's say I'm using span8 and span4.  I can't figure out how to force the iPad portrait view to stack the span4 under span8.

I have the correct tags in the head section, viewport and responsive CSS files.

Any ideas?

Updated:

Here is what I have. I can see how it be responsive when I shrink the webbrowser windows (eventually the span4 gets shifted under the span8). If I am in portrait mode on the iPad, don't want span8 and span4 to be stacked next to each other, instead I want span8 and then span4 to be stacked below span8.

in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

in body

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span8">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php    the_title( ); ?></a></h4>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="span4">
hello this is a test to see if columns are fluid.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

in footer

```
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you jsfiddle or for better responsive use `row-fluid` link http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrange in the following way :
[Jsfiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/FB8rP/4/show)

After the new explanation of question , Please use the following in your stylesheet or write your own media queries like below  :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
float: none;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
 }
}
```

In Header section bootstrap css (cloud hosted version)

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> /*bootstrap css with responsive css as well */

<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> /*your custom stylesheet*/
```

In body use following :

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="span4">Content</div>
<div class="span8">content</div>
</div>
```

In footer :

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I updated my code, I think I have it correct and I added another explanation of what I am trying to do.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: You will have to write media queries for it .. I ll update the answer in a bit

Comment: @Giventoflyfish Update the answer plz check .

Comment: Shail, Thanks! that worked!  I'll need to review see why but that did the trick.

Comment: @Giventoflyfish Remember whenever you want to do customize anything for tablet mobile or iphone just use media queries ...

Comment: At first I thought the responsive thingy was built into Twitter Bootstrap.